# Bah ! qui est-ce qui n’a pas cinquante ans ? quelques blancs-becs peut-être !

Tags: vocabulaire

M. Larose veut dire quoi exactement?

Voici le contexte:

> 'Quant aux prêtres, c’était l’abbé Halma, le même à qui M. Larose, son
>   collaborateur à la Foudre, disait : Bah ! qui est-ce qui n’a pas
>   cinquante ans ? quelques blancs-becs peut-être !

[…]

Voici le livre duqel ce passage a été extrait: [Les Misérables — Tome III : Marius (1862)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Et voici quelques interprétations de ce passage: [Bah ! qui est-ce qui n’a pas cinquante ans ? quelques blancs-becs peut-être !](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/bah-qui-est-ce-qui-n%E2%80%99a-pas-cinquante-ans-quelques-blancs-becs-peut-%C3%AAtre.3521671/)

Answer (score 3):

M. Larose disait à l’abbé Halma :

> qui est-ce qui n’a pas cinquante ans ? quelques blancs-becs peut-être !

En disant ceci, il **exprime son opinion sur les gens moins âgés que lui**. Son opinion est négative, et même hautaine face aux plus jeunes, car il utilise le terme :

> blancs-becs

Ce terme signifie des **jeunes hommes sans expérience et prétentieux**.

Source de la définition : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/blanc-bec_blancs-becs/9734